# Ruby - Can't find a string in a txt file

Tags: ruby, string, search

I'm writing a code to search a string in all txt files of a directory. The code works ok in 2 of of 3 files.

```
search = ['first', 'second', ...] 

Dir["directory/*.txt"].each do |txt|
  file = File.read(txt, encoding: "ISO8859-1:utf-8") 
  search.each do |se|
    puts se if file.include? se  #added to see if it finds a record - not working
    file.each_line do |li|
      if li.include? se
        puts li # I removed everything else to see if this works - not working
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Like I said before, It works fine with 2/3 files (80 MB, 88 MB, 224 MB). I left just the 224 MB file in the directory (the one that is not working), but still nothing.

I have been searching all day, but didn't find something that would help me. Why would not work in the 224 MB file, if has the same txt format and its from the same source.

**EDIT:**
Not working because doesn't find the string that I know is there and only happens for the third file mentioned.

**Edit2:**

I did `li.split("\t")` and know that `li[2]` its the column that I know the search string is.

Then changed the code to:

```
file.each_line.with_index do |li, line|
  data = li.split("\t")
  if line == 3
    puts data[2] #I got in console the string that i'm looking for
  end
# but then when i try to use it I cant
if data[2] == search #this is false i tried change both .to_s or .to_i
 puts li
end
```

I did another test like:

```
puts data[2].to_i + 1 #result is 1 when data[2] is just numbers
```

I downloaded again the file and try it again, but nothing seems to work. its like it can return the string `data[2]` but dont recognize it or cant do anything with it. And like I said, is just in 1 file out of 3.

[EDIT]
Problem was that txt files were damage from source, months later I try again this code with new generated txt files, and this worked with no issues.
Thanks all for comments and answers

Comment: Define "not working"

Comment: try adding brakets on your includes `if li.include?(se)`

Comment: doesnt find the search string, that i know is in the file

Comment: Does the search string contain any non-ASCII characters?

Comment: @tadman no, just normal characters normal columns name description code value1 value2 etc.. same format as other 2 files that are working ok

Comment: Either the string exists, exactly, or it doesn't. `include?` isn't going to lie. There may be invisible characters or UTF-8 bytes in the file that isn't matching because it's not a precise match. Look at the hex level if you have to. You might also compare vs. `grep`.

Comment: So 'li.lines.grep'  finds the string but when run the complete script, takes forever and the process is killed so can't use it.. I'm trying to find any workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen similar issues when working with strings that exceed the threshold of some memory limitation somewhere.

I would try breaking the large files up into smaller chunks like this:

```
FILE_SIZE_LIMIT_IN_MB = 80

search = ['first', 'second', ...]

def read_file(path)
  File.open(path, 'r') do |f|
    until f.eof? do
      yield f.read(FILE_SIZE_LIMIT_IN_MB * 1024 * 1024)
    end
  end
end

Dir["directory/*.txt"].each do |txt|
  read_file(txt) do |file|
    search.each do |se|
      puts se if file.include? se  #added to see if it finds a record - not working
      file.each_line do |li|
        if li.include? se
          puts li # I removed everything else to see if this works - not working
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but also if I do it like this it doesn't recognize the string (using `.include?` or `match`) unless I use `grep`  and this collapse memory and the process kills itself

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are searching line-by-line. If so, you can save a ton of memory overhead and searching through arrays by reading line by line. In order to to that, you'll wan to move the `search.each` loop inside the loop that reads the files. Here's my attempt:

```
search = ['first', 'second', ...] 

Dir["directory/*.txt"].each do |txt|
  File.foreach(txt, {encoding: "ISO8859-1:utf-8"}) do |li|
    search.each do |se|
      puts se if li.include? se
    end
  end
end
```

The [`foreach` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/IO.html#method-c-foreac) doesn't slurp in the entire file.

This doesn't work if the search string stretches across a newline barrier. If you have some other separator that would work better, you can optionally override the default:

```
File.foreach(txt, "\t", {encoding: "ISO8859-1:utf-8"}) do |r| # Tab-separated records
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i try with this approach and the result is the same, I think the third file have a different encoding, because when I compare `se.bytes` with the same string of the `li`  block `li_string.bytes`, bytes are ex: [12, 22, 30] [0,12,0,22,0,30], so problem maybe with encoding, but its wired because all files are from same source .